# What does "look for" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

What does "look for" mean in football (soccer) context?

15 min: Spurs 0 Zagreb 0
Lamela **looks for** Kane in the box but just puts too much on the cross. Spurs are well on top and looking threatening.

Comment: It means that it tries to see whether he can pass the ball to Kane, who is close to the opponents' goal, and may be able to score.

Comment: This is not a football-specific usage.  Did you check the dictionary for a definition of the phrasal verb "look for" before posting?  If so, why did you think it doesn't apply here?  Please do a bit of basic research before posting and explain your research in the question.

Answer (score 1):

According to **[Needgrammar](https://www.needgrammar.com/grammar/phrasal-verbs-types-with-examples.html)**, "look for" is:

a phrasal verb and it means "to try to find something"

as in the example "They went to the city to look for some new clothes."

[image]

source: https://www.needgrammar.com/grammar/phrasal-verbs-types-with-examples.html